# How to avoid false positive during automated testing select option?

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I am using Katalon Recorder 3.6.11 to generate automated test scripts.

I ran into an issue where selecting an option from a dropdown menu was passed during the automated test, but in testing by hand was failing.

When testing by hand, you could open the dropdown menu, and click on an option, but the selecting click was being stolen by another component on the screen, so the click didn't actually select the option, and no value was getting set in the select menu.

In the automated test, I was using `select | //select[@id="target"] | value` and it was selecting the appropriate option as expected.

I'm trying to figure out another way to select options from the dropdown menu that would involve clicking on the select component to open the menu, and then clicking on the actual option listed, but using commands like `click` or `clickAt` or `mouseDown` don't actually open the dropdown list. The `click` command does click on the component, it just doesn't open the menu. I realize that using a non-select based component that mimics the dropdown menu behavior can make this possible. But for accessibility reasons, we really want to stick with the select component as the user is only going to be selecting a single text option.

Does anyone have a way to test select components that uses clicks to open the menu and click on the option?

For reference, I'm just using a basic select component.

```html
<select id="target">
  <option value="0">Choose a value</option>
  <option value="1">value 1</option>
  <option value="2">value 2</option>
  <option value="3">value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Normally selenium is aware if some other element would steal a click (there's even a special exception for that), so you don't need to search for alternative clicking method, rather search what is visually different when you are running manually. So do you run automated test on the same type of browser, and browser with the same dimensions? Then run automated test and then pause it before `select`. Try to click select manually: is there still a problem, or can you click it?